# How do I create a variable that I can manipulate and access from anywhere in my code?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

struct Payment: Decodable {
    let salonvo:Bool
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var paidInd: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "http://www.repdeputy.com/payment.php"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            //perhaps check err
            //also perhaps check response status 200 OK

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let payment = try JSONDecoder().decode(Payment.self, from: data)
                print(payment.salonvo)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I need to set "payment.salonvo" as a variable that I can manipulate within the do{} and access in the regular ViewDidLoad function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting *payment* as a let and is defined inside the ***do***, so it cannot be accessed outside.

So I would create a var, next to *paidInd*, like `var payment:Payment? = nil`.  Then later inside the ***do***, use payment = (remove the let).

Then you could create a method that test if nil otherwise sets the *salonvo* Bool.  (Better would be use DidSet {} inside the var payment declaration.)

Answer (score 0):

Because the api call is asynchronous , you can't manipulate/use `payment.salonvo` until the response returns , if the bool value is related to a UI change then you have to dim the display with activityIndicator or similar until response returns then remove it inside the completion

Comment: Is there anyway to implement a stall time so I can set it as a variable?

Comment: you can create initial bool value

Comment: I tried doing that but it hasn't changed anything. The value always stays the same as how I initialized it. It's like what is happening in the do{} doesn't affect anything else in the code.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the value is only changed AFTER the response returns?